# Android Can not connect to .net web service

Tags: android, soap

I'm trying to connect web service with my android application butt it have an error when declare SoapObject. Please help me to resolve them!! Thank you verymuch. This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final String Soap_Action = "http://huroid.com/AndroidGetAllUser";
    final String Soap_MethodName = "AndroidGetAllUser";
    final String Soap_NameSpace = "http://huroid.com/";
    final String Soap_URL = "http://huroid.com/UserService.asmx?op=AndroidGetAllUser";

    //CallService
    try{

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Soap_NameSpace, Soap_Action);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    adpUser.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

And error occur at this line :

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Soap_NameSpace, Soap_Action);
```

I don't undestand method to identify soap namespace and method. :(

Answer (score 0):

Type
http://huroid.com/UserService.asmx?wsdl

in any web browser and you will be displayed with available methods and soap namespace information with method parameters and return type.

Is this what you are asking ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the format:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
```

like:

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Soap_NameSpace, Soap_MethodName);
```

Note:

```
+ replace Soap_Action with Soap_MethodName
+ Soap_Action = Soap_Namespace + Soap_MethodName
```